# Why does my Nikon D3100 display 'File contains no image'?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100

My camera has been working fine. I keep it in it's protective carrying case - nothing damaging has ever happened to this camera.

I took it out a few days ago and the display showed that my file contained no data. Thinking this was strange, I took several pictures: it was VERY slow at letting me review my pictures but eventually I was able to see the few I had taken.

Several minutes later there were no pictures again and then the screen read that the 'memory card cannot be used and may be damaged'. I changed out cards and the same thing happens.

Sometimes the shutter would not even release when I take a picture, other times it will but shows a quick black image but then won't let me review it in playback mode.

I can't even get to playback mode! What is going on?

Comment: Did you try formatting the memory card inside the camera? You should try that (will delete all images on the card).

Comment: Are the cards supported by the camera?  If not are other similar sized cards by the same manufacturer which are supported/tested?

Comment: It can also be that the memory card contacts inside the camera are either dirty or damaged. Verify your cards with an external reader. If the same issue happens with more than one card, the trouble is in your camera, not with the cards. Also, is the battery fully charged? Some noname cards misbehave if they do not get nominal voltage.

Comment: Micaela hasn't been on the site since around the time the question was asked.  Both answers address card issues, which this apparently is not, since it happened after swapping cards.  Voting to close as I think we'd need further information that isn't going to be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

> Several minutes later there were no pictures again and then the screen read that the 'memory card cannot be used and may be damaged'.

This is a very strong indication that your memory card may be damaged.  That probably means throw it out and buy a new one.  They aren't that expensive these days.

Even if you can get the card to work again, it's not worth continuing to use a card that you already suspect has problems.  A card that has had problems in the past is much more likely to have problems in the future, even if you believe the problem is gone.

It's a fact of life that some SD cards fail at random times, and sometimes this means they'll fail when they're quite new.  Count yourself lucky that you haven't lost a bunch of irreplaceable photographs that were on it.

Before you throw it in the trash, however, a few simple troubleshooting steps:

- Try another SD card in the same device.  Same problem?  Then it's probably the device, not the card.
- Try the problem SD card in a different device.  Any problems?  Then it's probably the card.  A lack of problems does not rule out the card having problems, though.
- Check for dust/dirt/fluff in the SD card slot of the device (camera) and on the SD card's contacts (avoid cleaning them unnecessarily especially with dry fabric, as static electricity is harmful to them).

Comment: The OP has the problem on multiple cards which would rule out a card issue.  There could be some lint or crud in there somewhere though.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that.  She did say "I changed out cards and the same thing happens" but I didn't find it clear whether that meant she tried a *different* card.  Either way, the troubleshooting steps I provided in my dots points still apply.

Answer (score 0):

With the d3#$$ series if you set the picture control and then shoot in auto then playback you will get folder contains no images message. No error just wont put image on card. Works only in semi automatic and manual mode. Try it and you will see.

Answer (score -1):

Copy everything off the memory card and then reformat it.  I would suggest you do a "test" on the card using your computer.  Copy known good files onto the card and then compare them to ensure there is no data corruption on the card (meaning no dead memory cells in the card).

Comment: It cannot be a card issue, the OP has the problem on multiple cards.